# At what angle do these curves cut one another?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm working on an exercise that asks this: At what angle do the curves $$y = 3.5x^2 + 2$$ and $$y = x^2 - 5x + 9.5$$ cut one another? I have set these equations equal to one another to find two values for x. Namely, $x = 1$ and $x = -3$ as intersections. How should I proceed? Most everyone here is always extremely helpful so I can't thank you all enough in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Find the slopes of their tangent lines at the point of intersection. Then trig should allow you to find the angle!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first step is to find the points of intersection, or at least their $x$-coordinates. You have done that.

We deal with the two points of intersection separately. We show how to work with $x=1$.

The derivative of $3.5x^2+2$ is $7x$. So the tangent line at $x=1$ has slope $7$.

Similarly, the tangent line to the other curve at $x=1$ has slope $-3$.

The angle at which the curves meet is the angle between their tangent lines.

Now there are many ways to proceed. We could use the calculator to find separately the angles the two lines make with the positive $x$-axis, and use the results to find the angle between the two lines.

Or else let these angles be $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Use the formula
$$\tan(\alpha-\beta)=\frac{\tan \alpha-\tan\beta}{1+\tan\alpha\tan\beta}.$$
We really want to find the *absolute value* of $\tan(\alpha-\beta)$. This is readily calculated, since you know that $\tan\alpha=7$ and $\tan\beta=-3$.

The arithmetic gives $\tan(\alpha-\beta)=\frac{10}{-20}$. Take the absolute value. We get $\frac{1}{2}$. So our angle is the angle between $0$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$ whose tangent is $\frac{1}{2}$.

If you are taking several variable calculus, or linear algebra, you will know other ways to find the angle between the two lines.

Repeat with $x=-3$.

Comment: Simply taking arctan of $\frac{1}{2}$ and converting to degrees must not be my next step as my answer doesn't line up with the answer in the book. Using $x = -3$ gives me the same tangent as $x = 1$ though. I'm not quite sure why our angle is between $0$ and $\frac{pi}{2}$. I may just be ignorant of a basic principle. Could you elaborate for me?

Comment: If you take two intersecting lines, they determine two angles, a "small" one ($\le 90^\circ$) and its supplement. Usually when we are asked for the angle between the lines, we pick the small one. By the way, what angles does your book give?

Comment: I see. The book gives two angles, it gives 153 degrees and 26 minutes, and the angle 2 degrees 28 minutes.

Comment: The $153^\circ 26'$ one has tangent very close to $-\frac{1}{2}$. In our calculation of $\tan(\alpha-\beta)$ we got $-\frac{1}{2}$. So it looks as though the book uses whatever number comes out of the calculation. I do not see a good argument for not using the "small" angle, about $26^\circ 34'$. There **is** a notion of directed angle, how much you rotate one to get to the other. For that, we use whatever comes out of the formula I gave, in this case $-\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Using the formula you gave above, my calculations for the tangent of $\frac{1}{2}$ gives 26 degrees 34 minutes as well. My calculations for using $x = -3$ as an x-coordinate, I get $tan(\Alpha - \Beta) = \frac{5}{116}$ which in terms of degrees gives the desired angle in the book being 2 degrees 28 minutes. I can't really figure out how we are getting 153 degrees 26 minutes though. Pardon my formatting, I really need to read over LaTex when I have more time.

Comment: The $153^\circ26'$ is the supplementary angle to $26^\circ34'$. It can be obtained mechanically as the angle between $0$ and $180$ whose tan is $-\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: I understand completely. Thanks Andre. Very beneficial information that you have provided.

Comment: You are welcome. The angle between two curves at a point where they meet is the angle between the tangent lines (if they exist) at that point. There are some disagreements about what that means, since if you draw two intersecting lines, they determine two angles, like $50^\circ$ and $130^\circ$ (the sum is $180$ always). The book just used the formula, found the angle between $0$ and $180$ whose tan is $-1/2$.

Answer (score 1):

Think of the curves as being defined by implicit equations $f(x,y)=y - 3.5x^2 - 2=0$ and $g(x,y)=y - x^2 +5x - 9.5=0$. Then the angle between the curves will be the angle between the normal vectors, which are gradients of the two functions $f$ and $g$.

Answer (score 0):

Compute the angles between the vectors $$(1, f'(x_i)), (1, g'(x_i))$$ using the formula
$$\cos(\phi) \cdot \Vert u \Vert_2 \Vert v \Vert_2 = \langle u,v \rangle_2$$
Denoting the standard euclidean norm and inner product on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 0):

You know the curves cut themselves at $x=1$ and $x=-3$. Let's consider a general case you might find helpful. Consider two functions $f,g$ that intersect at a point $x=\xi$.

Consider now the tangent line of $f$ at $x=\xi$. What angles does it make with the $x$ axis? It shouldn't be new news that $\tan\theta=f'(\xi)$. Similarily, the tangent line of $g$ at $x=\xi$ makes an angle $\eta$ with $\tan\eta =g'(\xi)$. So at what angle do these lines cross? Would you be convinced it must be $\rho=\theta-\eta$? You can make a drawing, and of course choose $\theta$ to be the largest angle. But we know that $$\tan(\theta-\eta)=\frac{\tan\theta-\tan\eta}{1+\tan\theta\tan\eta}$$

That is, $$\tan(\rho)=\frac{f'(\xi)-g'(\xi)}{1+f'(\xi)g'(\xi)}$$

You should be careful about the angles you're dealing with so as not to get any "off-set" results!